# Facebook's SDK for Unity working on iPad but not on iPhone

Tags: ios, facebook, unity-game-engine, url-scheme, facebook-unity-sdk

I am developing a game with Unity 3D (version 4.3.4f1) and I want to add it the facebook's share button (I am using the facebook's plugin for Unity version 5.1, more specifically function FB.Feed). My game is for android and iOS, which means that **the same app works on android, iPhone and iPad**.

I have created **one app on the facebook developers web** and I have the **share button already working on android and iPad**, but when I run **the same code in the iPhone** the game works fine but the share button doesn't and I **get the following error** after pressing it:

```
2014-05-28 21:25:39.715 PlaneCrush[1202:60b] FBSDKLog: Invalid use of FBAppCall, fbxxxxxxxxxxxxxios 
is not registered as a URL Scheme. Did you set 'FacebookUrlSchemeSuffix' in your plist?
```

**To reuse the same facebook app** on android and iOS I have added the **URL Scheme Suffix "ios"** to my app configuration at developers.facebook.com, to the facebook's plugin for Unity (ios Build Settings) and to the Xcode plist.info with key "FacebookUrlSchemeSuffix". If I have understood well, I should create another suffix if I had two different apps for iPhone and iPad, but I only have one app for iOS, one Apple ID, so I guess I wouldn't need any other Facebook Url Scheme Suffix. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks you in advance

Comment: I'm still stuck on this, can anyone atleast tell if my last paragraph makes sense? Have I understood when FacebookUrlSchemeSuffix is needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After wasting lot of time I have found the problem: Facebook App (installed on the iphone) was somehow conflicting with my game, after unistalling the Facebook App, my share button works on the iphone too.

Comment: that doesn't sound like a solution! can't make all my users uninstall fb.